# QEMU in Linux container connected to over SSH

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, centos, putty, qemu

I have been trying to use QEMU to get a VM (CentOS) running hosted in a container that I use a Putty SSH session to connect to. It seems I have issues with the serial input. I am using this command `qemu-system-x86_64 -nographic -cdrom CentOS.iso`. I see some typical serial output to the window with the last line saying “press enter to initialize” and after about 10 seconds the serial output moved down and the screen is black. Pressing enter or any other key does not affect this session, but if I kill the qemu process in another terminal anything I typed will be in the console I started the VM in. So you will see killed than the nonsense I may have typed. So this seems to be a serial input issue. Anyone have some experience with this?